# Comparar valores de linhas em um data frame - R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tenho um data frame com mais de 1 milhão de linhas e preciso contar o número de ocorrências de uma variável. Porém, o valor encontrado tem que ser inserido em uma nova coluna "qtde" e os valores tem que iniciar no valor mínimo de ocorrência (1) até o valor N total. É um pouco complicado explicar, então deixo neste link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15TjkKfFm7o0PPqvOWJPMGCkZCKV1O0JmKpxnvWwRv7g/edit?usp=sharing uma parte do data frame para que vocês possam visualizar e entender melhor. Lembrando que, não posso sumarizar o data frame. Tipo, encontrar os valores diferentes da variável "key_find" pela quantidade de vezes que a mesma aparece e sim, manter a quantidade de linhas originais no arquivo e acrescentar o valor da quantidade 1 até o limite encontrado na nova variável, coluna "qtde"

Esse é o código que escrevi, porém não esta funcionando:

```
Count_Qualific <- Count_Qualific %>% 
mutate(qtde = for (i in seq_along(key_find)) {
  if_else(key_find[i] = key_find[i - 1], 1 + qtde[i], qtde[i])
})
```

Saida:

```
Erro: '=' inesperado in:
"  mutate(qtde = for (i in seq_along(key_find)) {
    if_else(key_find[i] ="
>   })
Erro: '}' inesperado in "  }"
>
```

[image: Tabela de exemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser resolvido com `ave`. Não são necessários loops `for` nem pacotes extra. E o `ave` é razoavelmente rápido.

```
qtde <- with(Count_Qualific, ave(key_find, key_find, FUN = seq_along))
Count_Qualific$qtde <- as.integer(qtde)
```

---

Uma solução `dplyr` será a seguinte.

```
library(dplyr)

Count_Qualific %>%
  group_by(key_find) %>%
  mutate(qtde = seq_along(key_find))
```

---

Apesar de não ser pedido, aqui vai uma solução `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Count_Qualific)[, qtde := seq_along, by = key_find]
```

Comment: A gente complica as coisas... Muito obrigado Rui Barradas peja ajuda! Problema resolvido com sucesso!